# RDP ServerStartProgram Parameter

Tags: delphi, parameters, remoteapp

I use

```
rdp.RemoteProgram.ServerStartProgram('||applicationName', '', server_name, false, '', false);
```

to start the program from server and it's working fine

But now am trying to start a program with a parameter
where should I put the parameter to pass it to the application

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServerStartProgram()` is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382952(VS.85).aspx).

```
HRESULT ServerStartProgram(
  [in] BSTR         bstrExecutablePath,
  [in] BSTR         bstrFilePath,
  [in] BSTR         bstrWorkingDirectory,
  [in] VARIANT_BOOL vbExpandEnvVarInWorkingDirectoryOnServer,
  [in] BSTR         bstrArguments,
  [in] VARIANT_BOOL vbExpandEnvVarInArgumentsOnServer
);
```

> bstrArguments [in]
>
> The command-line arguments for the RemoteApp
>   program that are specified in bstrExecutablePath. Set this to NULL if
>   bstrExecutablePath is not specified.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot tom You'r right
but what I was't know is how to using it

with some googleit :)

```
rdp.RemoteProgram.ServerStartProgram
   ('||applicationName', '', server_name, false, '-1 parameter', false);
```

where (-1) is the parameter name or id at the application
and (parameter) is the value to pass it